# Parse multipart form data and then upload a file with Multer (Node module)

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

I'm having some troubles trying to figure out how to prevent Multer from uploading a file if an entry has already been added to the database.

In my scenario, I have a multipart form where you can add beers specifying an id. It has 2 inputs, one with a text input (id) and another one with a file input (beerImage).

What I'd like to do is, before uploading a file, check if it already exist in the database and, if not, upload the file. Currently, my code is uploading the file first and then checking if it exists, and that's a bad thing!

That's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var database = require('../services/database');

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'beerImage', maxCount: 1 } ]);

router.route('/beers')
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        // I'd like to use req.body.id in the query here, but it doesn't exist yet!
        cpUpload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(new Error('Error uploading file: ' + err.message + ' (' + err.field + ')'));
            } else {
                database.getConnection().done(function (conn) {
                    conn.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS beersCount FROM beers WHERE id=?', req.body.id, function (err, rows, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            conn.release();
                            return next(err);
                        }

                        if (rows[0].beersCount > 0) {
                            conn.release();
                            return next(new Error('Beer "' + req.body.id + '" already exists!'));
                        } else {
                            delete req.body.beerImage;
                            conn.query('INSERT INTO beers SET ?', req.body, function (err, rows, fields) {
                                conn.release();

                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                }

                                res.json({ message: 'Beer "' + req.body.id + '" added!' });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

I can't find a way to first "parse" the multipart form data (to be able to do the query and check if it exists using req.body.id) and then decide if I want to upload the file or not. It seems that "cpUpload" does both things at the same time!

Any idea of how to get "req.body.id" first (to do the query) and then decide if I want to upload the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized there is a function called "fileFilter" on Multer where you can control which files are accepted. Here I've been able to do the desired query to check if the entry exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the file before testing if it exists. And then save it or drop it

Comment: Is this the only solution, create a temp file?

Comment: This is a security for users. You can't access the file on client side.

Comment: Node.js runs on the server and it's there where I'd like to check if the entry exists before saving it.

Comment: And how exactly do you check the files are the same ? The only way is to hash them (md5, ..) and compare the checksums. And to hash the new file, it is more convenient to upload it before...

Comment: I know the file exists because I have an entry in the database. In fact, that's what I need, check if there is an entry in the db and, if there is already one, don't upload the file.

Comment: So in your database you have an entry but what do you use to tell if the files are identical ? the name ? the size ? If it is the case, that is not a good way to do it. The only way to be sure the files are identical, not matter their names are, is the way I described above.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explained it very well. I have a CMS where you can set an ID and select a file to upload it to the server. Then, I don't need to check if the files are identical or not, I just need to prevent uploading the file if there is already an entry in the db with the same provided ID. Currently the file is being overwritten because Multer first upload the file and then I'm able to do the query. The problem is that I would need to do the query before uploading the file!

Comment: So let Multer upload it in a temporary folder `var upload = multer({ dest: 'tmp/' });` and then remove it if it already exists. Otherwise, move it into the good folder `uploads/`

Answer (score 0):

- This is how I achieved file fields and text fields validation of `multipart/formdata` **before uploading to the cloud**. My `filterFile` function inside `multer` looks like this:
- Note any data sent using postman's formdata is considered as `multipart/formdata`. You have to use multer or other similar library in order to parse formdata.
- For `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `raw` data from postman does not require multer for parsing. You can parse these data either using `body-parser` or express built-in middlewares `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded({ extended: false, })`

```
        filterFile = async (req, file, cb) => {
        // if mimetypes are expected mimetypes

        const allowedMimeTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"];
        if (allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
          // then validate formdata fields
          // reject the request with error if any validation fails

          try {
            let { highlights, specifications, ...rest } = req.body;

            // deserializing string into respective javascript object(here into an array datatype) to facilate validation
            highlights = JSON.parse(req.body.highlights);
            specifications = JSON.parse(req.body.specifications);
            
            // constructing deserialized formdata
            const formdata = { highlights, specifications, ...rest };

            // using Joi for validation
            let skuAndProductResult = await skuAndProductSchema.validateAsync(
              formdata
            );

            if (skuAndProductResult) {
              // accept the fields and proceed to the next middleware
              cb(null, true);
              return;
            }

            // reject the request with error
            cb(true, false);
            return;
          } catch (err) {
            // reject the request with error
            cb(err, false);
          }
        } else {
          // To reject this file pass `false`
          cb(`${file.mimetype} is not supported`, false);
        }
      };
```