# Postman raw data works but form-data not works on POST request in node

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I'm facing some problem when using postman. When I'll try to send raw data in JSON(application/json) format, it get success.

[Postman sending post request and succeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcKhB.png)

But when I'll try to send form data it returns some error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": {
            "name": {
                "message": "Path `name` is required.",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "name"
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "name",
                "$isValidatorError": true
            },
            "price": {
                "message": "Path `price` is required.",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "price"
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "price",
                "$isValidatorError": true
            }
        },
        "_message": "Product validation failed",
        "message": "Product validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., price: Path `price` is required.",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

[Postman errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRMnz.png)

And here is my project code snippets

**product.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Product from '../models/product.model';

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    });
    product.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Created product successfully',
            createdProduct: {
                name: result.name,
                price: result.price,
                _id: result._id,
                request: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: `http://localhost:3000/products/${result._id}`
                }
            }
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

**product.model.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Answer (score 7):

you missing

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

then try in `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: ```x-www-form-urlencoded``` works but ```form-data``` doesn't

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? mine is also working for x-www-form-urlencoded but not form-data

Comment: This worked for me but the data came over in a weird format, almost like partial JSON. My first array was wrapped in double quotes but the key for it wasn't. My second array was wrapped in single quotations and the key was also an object key, not a string.

Answer (score 6):

- Any data sent using `postman's formdata` is considered as `multipart/formdata`. You have to use multer or other similar library in order to parse formdata.
- For `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `raw` data from postman, does not require multer for parsing. You can parse these data either using `body-parser` or express built-in middlewares `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded({ extended: false, })`
- Since multer returns a middleware, you can only access `req.body` inside multer(i.e fileFilter) or in the middleware that comes after multer BUT NOT BEFORE if you have not used multer as global middleware(which is bad idea).

for code snippets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68588435/10146901

Answer (score 5):

Use multer middleware:

```js
const upload = require('multer')();

route.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    // your code...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use body-parser.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then just add in your code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Details can be found https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Sorry! I've a file duplication on product.js. I simply remove that file and now it works for me.

Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: I don't have any duplication of the file then also I am getting the error. It happens when I try with form-data, If  I am trying with row data its giving right output. But when I give with form data its shows error.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using body-parser, it will still return empty req.body that will lead to errors because you have validation in place. The reason it is returning empty req.body when sending POST request using form-data tru Postman is because body-parser can't handle multipart/form-data. You need a package that can handle multipart/form-data like multer. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer. Try using that package.

Answer (score 0):

- Use multer for get form data
- inside upload function you can get req.body from form data

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 0):

Use express-fileupload middleware instead of multer.

```
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload'
app.use(fileUpload())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In product.js include:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
```

and select `raw` (then select JSON from last dropdown) or `x-www-form-urlencoded`